# Encoding in UTF-8 instead of ASCII - SilverStripe

Tags: validation, silverstripe

I'm using 2.4.7 and I want to include some validation for two fields which take in prices (e.g. €1 or 2 for €3).  Originally I thought that perhaps I would need to resort to validating user input but as the answer suggests it was a database issue.

The encoding within SilverStripe was defaulting to ASCII which converted the symbols such as the euro symbol.  In the end I need to add

```
$this->response->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset='utf-8'");
```

to the init method in the controller.  This corrected the encoding issue and prevented a hacky workaround taking place.  Many thanks for the insight on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this in the CMS. If that's the case, the easiest way is probably to create a new class which extends the `TextField` class and adds a `public function validate()` method which performs your validation (see the [CreditCardField class](http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/forms/fields-formattedinput/CreditCardField.html) for an example).

```
class FancyCurrencyField extends TextField {
    public function validate($validator) {
        // Do your validation
        if ($invalid) {
            $validator->validationError(
                $this->name,
                "Please don't use currency symbols.",
                "validation",
                false
            );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Once you've created your class, you can modify the form fields in your `getCMSFields()` function on the `DataObject` and use the new class in place of `TextField`.

Having said that, it feels like output encoding and not input validation is the root cause of your problem. I'd check to make sure that everything is setup to use UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @drzax.  I've read a few places that the UTF-8 thing could be my problem.  I've checked the database and the _config.php file and they use utf8_general_ci and utf-8 respectively. Is there somewhere else I should be checking?

Comment: If the character is still displaying correctly in the CMS after saving  the problem must be somewhere between where it comes out of the database and wherever you're using it. I'd start by debugging right before where you're converting it to JSON and make sure it's stil correct there, then just work your way through the rest of the output code.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem with the PHP function substr. I just used mb_substr instead and it solved my issue.

Please view http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/11797#post369831